# Odoo 10: enter value in Many2one field dynamically

Tags: python, select, odoo

I added in my models.py :

```
commercial_group = fields.Many2one("simcard.simcard")
```

and in my views.xml :

```
<field name="commercial_group" widget="selection"/>
```

And then i am trying to create a new record in my model like this :

```
record.sudo().create({
                                     "icc": icc.text,
                                     "imsi": imsi.text,
                                     "msisdn": msisdn.text,
                                     "lte_status": lte_status.text,
                                     "life_cycle_status": life_cycle_status.text,
                                     "sim_model": simmodel.text,
                                     "gprs_status": gprsStatus.text,

                                     "consumption_monthly_data_limit": consumption_monthly_data_limit.text,
                                     "consumption_monthly_data_value": consumption_monthly_data_value.text,
                                     "consumption_monthly_data_thrReached": consumption_monthly_data_thrReached.text,

                                     "commercial_group": commercial_group.text,

                                     "country": country.text,
                                     "operator": operator.text

                                       })
              http.request.env.cr.commit()
```

and i get this error in my logs :

```
INFO test odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "simcard_simcard" ("id", "consumption_monthly_data_limit", "consumption_monthly_data_thrReached", "msisdn", "country", "lte_status", "consumption_monthly_data_value", "life_cycle_status", "icc", "gprs_status", "sim_model", "operator", "commercial_group", "imsi", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('simcard_simcard_id_seq'), '0', '0', '34590169', 'CH', 'false', '0', 'ACTIVE', '89293165951', '2', 'M2M Plug-in', 're', '1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE', '29782', 1, 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
2018-09-19 13:44:27,441 5714 ERROR test odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 642, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 334, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 327, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 942, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 895, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/simcard/models/models.py", line 259, in sync
    parse.parseXml(subscriptionDatas)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/simcard/models/parse.py", line 71, in parseXml
    "operator": operator.text
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3846, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3941, in _create
    cr.execute(query, tuple(u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2))
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE"

                                                             ^
```

The error is in inserting the value in Commercial_group field because when i remove this field from record.sudo().create() statement, i dont get any error.

Am i missing any point here ??

Comment: Have you read the error message? It appears you're trying to insert a string into a database field that is set only to take integers

Comment: yes but why my field commercial_group = fields.Many2one("simcard.simcard")  is an integer field?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
"commercial_group": commercial_group.id
```

instead of commercial_group.text
because Many2one store as a id not text...

Comment: Not possible. i am getting commercial_group variable because i am parsing a SOAP response using Element tree: response=requests.post(self.url,cert=self.cert,data=body,headers=self.headers) ,element = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content.decode('utf-8')), body_el = element.find('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body')    ,                                 commercial_group=body_el.find('{http://www.example.com}commercialGroup') . So I can use only commercial_group.text variable. Otherwise i get this error: commercial_group.id, AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: then u should search that record id from specific model using commercial_group.text

Comment: sorry , i didnt understand. please explain the workflow

Comment: In avove error msg its saying you there are integer value require for that many2 one so you have string for that.  so first you should search that record from 'simacard. simcard' model after you can get integer id from that record so you can assign unto commercial_group

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a new record for commercial group according to the text that you get from the SOAP response and then create the main record with the id of the newly created record, Look below:

```
com_grp = self.env['simcard.simcard'].create({'name': commercial_group.text})
```

Then insert this in your main record:

`"commercial_group": com_grp.id` instead of `commercial_group.text`

Comment: will it not create 2 different rows in my table? because i am executing 'create' method 2 times . Once for com_grp and then for commercial_group